# npm publish .gitignored file

Tags: npm, gitignore, npm-publish

The situation is the following

I have a `.gitignore` file:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
/index.js # this is a build output, I don't want it in the repo
```

And a `package.json` file (just the relevant parts):

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "files": [
    "index.js", // however I want this in the npm package
    "readme.md",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js", // this builds index.js ...
    "lint": "eslint **/*.js --config .eslintrc",
    "test": "jest --no-cache",
    "prepublish": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run build" // ...before publishing
  }
}
```

When I published the first version of this, `index.js` was omitted, and only `readme.md` and `package.json` were properly published. The only thing I can assume is that `.gitignore` causes this, since according to the docs `.gitignore` substitutes `.npmignore` if the later is not present (or maybe the 2 are used together, no idea).

So is there a way to not have that file in the git repo, but have it in the npm package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to solve this by adding a `.npmignore` file:

```
# all the crap that's not neccessary for the npm module to work
node_modules
src
test
.babelrc
.eslintignore
.eslintrc
.gitignore
.npmignore
.travis.yml
rollup.config.js
```

And removing the `files` attribute completely from `package.json`.